# How to add new field in Product link section Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-product-attributes

I want to add new field in the magento 2 admin > product > downloadable information > and link details. Please check the screenshot attached
[image]

After some research, I am able to add field in UI

```
class LinksModifier
{
    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Links $subject,
        $result,
    ) {
        $result['downloadable']['children']['container_links']['children']['link']['children']['record']['children']['language'] = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => $this->getLanguageColumn(),
                ],
            ],
            'sortOrder' => 10,
        ];

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns language columns configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getLanguageColumn()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Language'),
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'componentType' => 'field',
            'dataType' => 'text',
            'dataScope' => 'language',
            'sortOrder' => 8,
            'options' => $this->toOptionArray(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 'en', 'label' => __('English')],
            ['value' => 'no', 'label' => __('Norwegian')],
        ];
    }
}
```

db_schema.xml file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
        <table name="downloadable_link">
            <column xsi:type="varchar" name="language" nullable="false" comment="Language"/>
        </table>
</schema>
```

So above code added field in the admin UI and created column in database table.

**What is the issue now?**
I cannot find a way to set and get the value from table.

Please share if someone knows how to set and get value from the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesn't work is because you created the input field and the field in the database, but there is no link between them.

We can also find a lot of protected methods in the LinkRepository class, especially where the actual saving of the link occurs *(see \Magento\Downloadable\Model\LinkRepository::saveLink for more details)*.
There are also a reconstruction of the link data which will be saved in those protected methods, which prevents us from creating a simple plugin to add the additional data into this array.

I created a module in order to add a custom field to the downloadable link.

As often, there is multiple ways to do it. A simpler way would be to do a few preferences to overwrite the code.

I prefered to use the ways Magento gives us to extend the existing code without rewriting things. This will guarantee a better compatibility between modules and future developments.
While I will explain how to use this features to add data to the downloadable link table, **this can also be used as a reference if you want to extend existing entities without overwriting the code**.

I will present you the differents files you need to create for each steps, with an explaination of why we need to do it.

For this example I created a module named "Vendor_AddFieldToDownloadableLink". You might need to modify the code a bit to match your own module name (module name, namespaces, imported classes, ...)

---

### 1. Create the base of the module.

First create the base of the module, as you already did (`registration.php` and `etc/module.xml` files)

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/registration.php** :

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Vendor_AddFieldToDownloadableLink', __DIR__);
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/etc/module.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_AddFieldToDownloadableLink">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Downloadable"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

### 2. Create a new table for the new attributes.

Magento often allow us to use "extension attributes" to add data to the existing entities without overwriting the code.
You can generaly see when you can use them by looking at the Interfaces of the entity you need to add data to.
In this case, we can see in the `\Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface` class allow us to use extension attributes (`getExtensionAttributes` and `setExtensionAttributes` methods).

To use this feature, we will not alter the existing table, but we will create a new table where our additional data will be stored (`db_schema.xml` and `db_schema_whitelist.json` files).

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/etc/db_schema.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="downloadable_link_language" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Downloadable Link Language Table">
        <column xsi:type="int" name="link_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Link ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="language" nullable="false" comment="Link Language"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="DOWNLOADABLE_LINK_LANGUAGE_LINK_ID_DOWNLOADABLE_LINK_ID" table="downloadable_link_language" column="link_id" referenceTable="downloadable_link"  referenceColumn="link_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="link_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/etc/db_schema_whitelist.xml** :

```
{
    "downloadable_link_language": {
        "column": {
            "link_id": true,
            "language": true
        },
        "constraint": {
            "PRIMARY": true,
            "DOWNLOADABLE_LINK_LANGUAGE_LINK_ID_DOWNLOADABLE_LINK_ID": true
        }
    }
}
```

*Tip : You can automatically generate the db_schema_whitelist.json for your modules by running the following command :*
`bin/magento setup:db-declaration:generate-whitelist --module-name=YourModule_Name`

### 3. Link the extension table with the original table

When using extension attributes, Magento will performs a few tasks automatically according to the link we declared between the entity and the extension attributes.
This link is declared in the extension_attributes.xml file.

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/etc/extension_attributes.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface">
        <attribute code="language" type="string">
            <join reference_table="downloadable_link_language" join_on_field="link_id" reference_field="link_id">
                <field column="language">language</field>
            </join>
        </attribute>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

*Check the `\Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper::populateWithArray` method for an example of Magento dealing with extension attributes.*

### 4. Create the Resource Models to interact with the new table

We will now create a few Resource Models to interact with this new table :

- one to *Save* a given value to the according link_id
- one to *Get* the data for a given link_id
- one to *Delete* the additional value of a given link_id

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/Model/ResourceModel/SaveDownloadableLinkLanguage.php** :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

/**
 * Save Downloadable Link Language by Link Id.
 */
class SaveDownloadableLinkLanguage
{
    private const LINK_ID = 'link_id';

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @param ResourceConnection $connection
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $connection
    ) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Save 'language' for given link id.
     *
     * @param int $linkId
     * @param string $language
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(int $linkId, string $language): void
    {
        $connection = $this->connection->getConnection();
        $table = $this->connection->getTableName('downloadable_link_language');

        $data = [
            self::LINK_ID => $linkId,
            'language' => $language
        ];

        $connection->insertOnDuplicate($table, $data);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/Model/ResourceModel/GetLanguageByDownloadableLinkId.php** :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

/**
 * Get Language by downloadable link identifier.
 */
class GetLanguageByDownloadableLinkId
{
    private const LINK_ID = 'link_id';

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @param ResourceConnection $connection
     */
    public function __construct(
        ResourceConnection $connection
    ) {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch 'language' by downloadable link identifier.
     *
     * @param int $linkId
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function execute(int $linkId): ?string
    {
        $connection = $this->connection->getConnection();
        $table = $this->connection->getTableName('downloadable_link_language');

        $columns = ['language' => 'language'];
        $select = $connection->select()
            ->from($table, $columns)
            ->where(self::LINK_ID . '= ?', $linkId)
            ->limit(1);

        $id = $connection->fetchOne($select);

        return $id ?: null;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/Model/ResourceModel/DeleteDownloadableLinkLanguage.php** :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

/**
 * Delete assignment of language to downloadable link.
 */
class DeleteDownloadableLinkLanguage
{
    private const LINK_ID = 'link_id';

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @param ResourceConnection $connection
     */
    public function __construct(ResourceConnection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Delete assignment of language to Downloadable Link.
     *
     * @param int $linkId
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(int $linkId): void
    {
        $connection = $this->connection->getConnection();
        $table = $this->connection->getTableName('downloadable_link_language');

        $connection->delete($table, [self::LINK_ID . ' = ?' => $linkId]);
    }
}
```

### 5. Create plugins to associate the additional data to the entity

Now that we have the necessary classes to manage the additional data, we need to use them at some key steps of the downloadable link life cycle.

- When a downloadable link is saved : we need to ensure our data in the extension attributes is also saved in our table, or deleted if it has been unset.
- When a downloadable link is loaded, to set our attribute in the extension attributes of the Link object.
- When a collection of link is loaded, to set our attribute in the extension attributes of each object of the collection.

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/Plugin/Downloadable/Link/ManageAssignmentOfLanguageToDownloadableLink.php** :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Plugin\Downloadable\Link;

use Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface;
use Magento\Downloadable\Model\LinkRepository;
use Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Model\ResourceModel\DeleteDownloadableLinkLanguage;
use Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Model\ResourceModel\SaveDownloadableLinkLanguage;

/**
 * Save or delete selected Language for Downloadable Link.
 */
class ManageAssignmentOfLanguageToDownloadableLink
{
    /**
     * @var SaveDownloadableLinkLanguage
     */
    private $saveDownloadableLinkLanguage;

    /**
     * @var DeleteDownloadableLinkLanguage
     */
    private $deleteDownloadableLinkLanguage;

    /**
     * @param SaveDownloadableLinkLanguage $saveDownloadableLinkLanguage
     * @param DeleteDownloadableLinkLanguage $deleteDownloadableLinkLanguage
     */
    public function __construct(
        SaveDownloadableLinkLanguage   $saveDownloadableLinkLanguage,
        DeleteDownloadableLinkLanguage $deleteDownloadableLinkLanguage
    ) {
        $this->saveDownloadableLinkLanguage = $saveDownloadableLinkLanguage;
        $this->deleteDownloadableLinkLanguage = $deleteDownloadableLinkLanguage;
    }

    /**
     * Save information about associate Language to Downloadable Link.
     *
     * @param LinkRepository $subject
     * @param int $result
     * @param string $sku
     * @param LinkInterface $link
     *
     * @return int
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterSave(LinkRepository $subject, $result, $sku, LinkInterface $link)
    {
        if (!$this->validateLink($link)) {
            return $result;
        }

        if (!$link->getExtensionAttributes()->getLanguage()) {
            $this->deleteDownloadableLinkLanguage->execute((int)$result);

            return $result;
        }

        $this->saveDownloadableLinkLanguage->execute(
            (int)$result,
            $link->getExtensionAttributes()->getLanguage()
        );

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Check if downloadable link can have a Language.
     *
     * @param LinkInterface $link
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function validateLink(LinkInterface $link): bool
    {
        return !!$link->getExtensionAttributes();
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/Plugin/Downloadable/Link/LoadLanguageForDownloadableLink.php** :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Plugin\Downloadable\Link;

use Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Downloadable\Model\ResourceModel\Link;
use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Model\ResourceModel\GetLanguageByDownloadableLinkId;

/**
 * Load Language for Downloadable Link.
 */
class LoadLanguageForDownloadableLink
{
    /**
     * @var GetLanguageByDownloadableLinkId
     */
    private $getLanguageByDownloadableLinkId;

    /**
     * @var LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @param GetLanguageByDownloadableLinkId $getLanguageByDownloadableLinkId
     * @param LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        GetLanguageByDownloadableLinkId $getLanguageByDownloadableLinkId,
        LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory
    ) {
        $this->getLanguageByDownloadableLinkId = $getLanguageByDownloadableLinkId;
        $this->linkExtensionInterfaceFactory = $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory;
    }

    /**
     * Load and add Language information to Downloadable.
     *
     * @param Link $subject
     * @param Link $result
     * @param AbstractModel $entity
     *
     * @return Link
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function afterLoad(Link $subject, Link $result, AbstractModel $entity): Link
    {
        if (!$entity->getId()) {
            return $result;
        }

        $language = $this->getLanguageByDownloadableLinkId->execute((int)$entity->getId());
        if (!$language) {
            return $result;
        }

        if (!$entity->getExtensionAttributes()) {
            $entity->setExtensionAttributes($this->linkExtensionInterfaceFactory->create());
        }

        $entity->getExtensionAttributes()->setLanguage($language);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/Plugin/Downloadable/LinkCollection/GetLanguageInformationPlugin.php** :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Plugin\Downloadable\LinkCollection;

use Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link;
use Magento\Downloadable\Model\ResourceModel\Link\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;

/**
 * Load Language and add to Extension Attributes.
 */
class GetLanguageInformationPlugin
{
    private const TABLE_ALIAS = 'dll';

    /**
     * @var LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory;

    /**
     * @var ResourceConnection
     */
    private $connection;

    /**
     * @param LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory
     * @param ResourceConnection $connection
     */
    public function __construct(
        LinkExtensionInterfaceFactory $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory,
        ResourceConnection $connection
    ) {
        $this->linkExtensionInterfaceFactory = $linkExtensionInterfaceFactory;
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Load information about Language to collection of Downloadable Link.
     *
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param \Closure $proceed
     * @param bool $printQuery
     * @param bool $logQuery
     *
     * @return Collection
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Select_Exception
     */
    public function aroundLoadWithFilter(
        Collection $collection,
        \Closure $proceed,
        bool $printQuery,
        bool $logQuery
    ): Collection {
        if ($collection->isLoaded()) {
            return $proceed($printQuery, $logQuery);
        }

        if (!isset($collection->getSelect()->getPart(Select::FROM)[self::TABLE_ALIAS])) {
            $table = $this->connection->getTableName('downloadable_link_language');
            $collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                [self::TABLE_ALIAS => $table],
                self::TABLE_ALIAS . '.link_id = main_table.link_id',
                ['language']
            );
        }

        $result = $proceed($printQuery, $logQuery);

        foreach ($collection as $link) {
            $this->processLink($link);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Process link entity.
     *
     * @param Link $link
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function processLink(Link $link): void
    {
        $hasDataChanges = $link->hasDataChanges();
        if ($link->getData('language')) {
            $this->addLanguageToExtensionAttributes($link);
        }
        $link->unsetData('language');
        $link->setDataChanges($hasDataChanges);
    }

    /**
     * Add Loaded Language to Extension Attributes.
     *
     * @param Link $item
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function addLanguageToExtensionAttributes(Link $item): void
    {
        if (!$item->getExtensionAttributes()) {
            $item->setExtensionAttributes($this->linkExtensionInterfaceFactory->create());
        }

        $item->getExtensionAttributes()->setLanguage(
            $item->getData('language')
        );
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/etc/di.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Downloadable\Model\ResourceModel\Link\Collection">
        <plugin name="add_language_to_downloadable_link" type="Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Plugin\Downloadable\LinkCollection\GetLanguageInformationPlugin" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Downloadable\Model\ResourceModel\Link">
        <plugin name="load_language_for_downloadable_link" type="Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Plugin\Downloadable\Link\LoadLanguageForDownloadableLink" />
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Downloadable\Model\LinkRepository">
        <plugin name="manage_assignment_of_language_to_downloadable_link" type="Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Plugin\Downloadable\Link\ManageAssignmentOfLanguageToDownloadableLink" />
    </type>
</config>
```

### 6. Add and populate the new field on the downloadable link form

Now that we have covered the necessary interactions between the downloadable link and our additional data, we can now add the new field to the downloadable link form on the product page.
As you already did, we will add the field to the UI construction through the `modifyMeta` method.

But instead of creating a plugin on the existing class, we will add our own modifier to the existing modifier pool on the downloadable product.

*See `\Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite` class and its usage on di.xml files for more info about its usage.*

Then, we will have to map the data from the extension attributes to the newly created field. This will be done via the modifyData method.

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/LinksLanguage.php** :

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country;
use Magento\Downloadable\Api\Data\LinkInterface;
use Magento\Downloadable\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form;

/**
 * Class adds a grid with links.
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class LinksLanguage extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @var Country
     */
    protected $country;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     * @param Country $country
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager,
        Country $country
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->country = $country;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $model = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $linkData = $this->getLinksData();
        foreach ($data[$model->getId()]['downloadable']['link'] as &$link) {
            $link['extension_attribute_language_language'] = $linkData[$link['link_id']]['language'] ?? null;
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Get Links data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getLinksData()
    {
        $linksData = [];
        if ($this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeId() !== Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE) {
            return $linksData;
        }

        $links = $this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeInstance()->getLinks($this->locator->getProduct());
        /** @var LinkInterface $link */
        foreach ($links as $link) {
            if ($link->getExtensionAttributes() && $link->getExtensionAttributes()->getLanguage()) {
                $linkData = [];
                $linkData['language'] = $link->getExtensionAttributes()->getLanguage();
                $linksData[$link->getId()] = $linkData;
            }
        }

        return $linksData;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $linksPath = Composite::CHILDREN_PATH . '/' . Composite::CONTAINER_LINKS . '/children/link/children/record/children/language';

        return $this->arrayManager->set(
            $linksPath,
            $meta,
            $this->getLanguageColumn()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns Language columns configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getLanguageColumn()
    {
        $languageField['arguments']['data']['config'] = [
            'label' => __('Language'),
            'formElement' => Form\Element\Select::NAME,
            'componentType' => Form\Field::NAME,
            'dataType' => Form\Element\DataType\Text::NAME,
            'dataScope' => 'extension_attribute_language_language',
            'sortOrder' => 55,
            'options' => $this->country->toOptionArray(),
        ];

        return $languageField;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/AddFieldToDownloadableLink/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Composite">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="linksLanguage" xsi:type="string">Vendor\AddFieldToDownloadableLink\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\LinksLanguage</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

I hope this will help you, or at least give you direction on where to look to do what you wanted.

Do not hesitate if anything is unclear or if you need more informations !

Answer (score 0):

To add the new field, you can follow these steps:

1. Create a new module.
2. In the module's `etc/di.xml` file, add the following configuration:
3. Create a new plugin class in the module's `Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable.php file.`

   ```
    <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;

    use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

    class Downloadable
    {
        public function afterToHtml(
            \Magento\Downloadable\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Downloadable $subject,
            AbstractElement $element
        ) {
            $element->addType('custom_field_type', \Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Downloadable\Element\Custom::class);
            return $element;
        }
    }
   ```
4. Create a new element class in the module's `Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Tab/Downloadable/Element/Custom.php` file.

   setDateFormat(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
            return parent::render($element);
        }
    }
5. Clear the Magento cache.

Once you have completed these steps, you will see a new field named "Custom Field" in the "Downloadable Information" tab of the product edit page. You can enter any value you want in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Your code added field in the admin UI and created column in database table but there are no class for save data and show data from database into product form. You need to add these feature.

Here's how to solve this problem:

When you save product type downloadable, everything is save except your custom field `language`. So you just need catch event after save product and save value of language into table `downloadable_link`.

In **Vendor/ModuleName/etc/events.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_catalog_product_save_entity_after">
        <observer name="save_language_link" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Product\SaveLanguageLink"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

In **Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Product\SaveLanguageLink.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Product;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Downloadable\Model\LinkFactory;

class SaveLanguageLink implements ObserverInterface {

    private LinkFactory $linkFactory;

    public function __construct(LinkFactory $linkFactory)
    {
        $this->linkFactory = $linkFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $links = $product->getDownloadableData()['link'] ?? [];
        if ($links) {
            foreach ($links as $link) {
                $linkId = $link['link_id'];
                $linkLanguage = $link['language'];
                $linkTitle = $link['title'];
                $model = $this->linkFactory->create()->load($linkId, 'link_id');
                $model->setLanguage($linkLanguage);
                $model->setTitle($linkTitle); //you need to save title too, if don't title will null in table `downloadable_link_title`
                $model->save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After add this change into module, when you save product type downloadable, you can see the value of custom field `language` in table `downloadable_link`. But this value not show in product form yet, so you need plugin with method `modifyData()` like you do with method `modifyMeta()`.

In **Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\LinksModifier.php** (this is your class but I also do plugin method `modifyData()`:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Downloadable\Model\LinkFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;

class LinksModifier
{
    private LinkFactory $linkFactory;
    private LocatorInterface $locator;

    public function __construct(LinkFactory $linkFactory, LocatorInterface $locator)
    {
        $this->linkFactory = $linkFactory;
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    public function afterModifyData (
        \Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Links $subject,
                                                                          $result,
    ) {
        try {
            $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
            $productId = $product->getId();
            $links = $result[strval($productId)]['downloadable']['link'];
            foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
                $model = $this->linkFactory->create()->load($link['link_id'], 'link_id');
                $result[strval($productId)]['downloadable']['link'][$key]['language'] = $model->getLanguage();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return $result;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function afterModifyMeta(
        \Magento\Downloadable\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Links $subject,
                                                                          $result,
    ) {
        $result['downloadable']['children']['container_links']['children']['link']['children']['record']['children']['language'] = [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => $this->getLanguageColumn(),
                ],
            ],
        ];

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns language columns configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getLanguageColumn()
    {
        return [
            'label' => __('Language'),
            'formElement' => 'select',
            'componentType' => 'field',
            'dataType' => 'text',
            'dataScope' => 'language',
            'options' => $this->toOptionArray(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return [
            ['value' => 'en', 'label' => __('English')],
            ['value' => 'no', 'label' => __('Norwegian')],
        ];
    }
}
```

After add these change, everything will working correctly like you want.

The reason why when you save product type downloadable but can not save custom field value because there are no code save this field. Look into field `\Magento\Downloadable\Model\Link\Builder`, you can see how Magento save data into table `downloadable_link` in function `build()` (they setField to save so the custom field is not in this code).

The reason why you need to save title again, you can debug and read in this function `\Magento\Downloadable\Model\ResourceModel\Link::saveItemTitleAndPrice()`.